# Scaling ggplot density-curve areas to reflect categorical prevalences

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is it possible to scale the density plots by category to represent their respective prevalences?  To illustrate:

```
set.seed(3)
dat = data.frame(x = sample(50), y = sample(c(rep(c('A','B'), each=23), rep('X', 4))))
table(dat$y)
 A  B  X 
23 23  4
ggplot(dat, aes(x, fill=y)) + geom_density(alpha=.3)
```

[image]

The curve for category X is normalised so it's area is (I'm guessing) equal to other categories.  If possible I'd like it to reflect X's small number of observations.  Grateful for pointers.

Comment: densities count to 1. a solution would be the inclusion of geom_rug, like so: ggplot(dat, aes(x, fill=y)) + geom_density(alpha=.3) + geom_rug() + facet_grid(y ~.)

Comment: `ggplot(dat, aes(x, y=..count.., fill=y)) + geom_density( alpha = .3)` for the shape (but really should be `..count../50`)

Comment: @user20650 thanks that's spot on. I wasn't aware of that formulation. Do you want to add that as an answer?

Comment: @Henk +1 for geom_rug

Comment: please feel free to write it up @geotheory

Comment: @Henk for some reason `geom_rug` seems to be incompatible with `y= ..count..` method..

Comment: @geotheory; tthis can be done by adding the count within the aes of geom_density rather than at the top level

Answer (score 1):

As per @user20650's comment:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x, y=..count.., fill=y)) + geom_density( alpha = .3)
```

And `..count../50` for correct y-axis density scale.

Comment: `/50` because your data holds 50 observations?

Comment: Well 7 years ago but looks like it!

Comment: Haha, cheers! Will setlle with that!